# How can i mannualy install packages in elementary os?

Tags: release-hera, software-installation, applications

I want to install mint service desk on my elementary os and for that I have to install a docker first, not happening. Can anyone please tell be which linux version package will support elementary os [ubuntu/centOS/debian etc}

Comment: What do you mean by ' that I have to install a docker first, not happening.' ? Is docker not installing? Or you do not want to install it? Try the official instructions for Ubuntu 18.04 https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Currently elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 18.04, so Ubuntu packages should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this with a little google search it explains:

How to install docker adding a repositiory.

How to install the verion that ubuntu/elementary has

How to run docker.

Hope it helps:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04